# Jquery && selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to check if every single div inside my div(with id#row1) has the property "pointer-events" set to "none". And only if **ALL OF THEM** have that property do something.

How I did it is very bad but it works:

```
if( $('#row1 div:nth-child(1)').css("pointer-events") === "none"){

    if( $('#row1 div:nth-child(2)').css("pointer-events") === "none"){Do something}}
```

Is there a simple way to check this? Something like this:

```
    if(($('#row1 div:nth-child(1) && #row1 div:nth-child(2)')).css("pointer-events") === "none"){
    Do something
}
```

Comment: Please show your HTML as well. That will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't seem to have a `.all` or `.every` method, but you can use `Array.prototype.every` (or `[].every`) for this:

```
var allHavePointerEventsNone = [].every.call($("#row1 div"), function(el) {
  return $(el).css("pointer-events") === "none";
});
```

Test:

```
// HTML
<div id="foo">
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="yes"></div>
</div>

<div id="bar">
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="no"></div>
</div>

// JS
console.log([].every.call($("#foo div"), function(el) {
  return $(el).hasClass("yes");
}));

console.log([].every.call($("#bar div"), function(el) {
  return $(el).hasClass("yes");
}));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/41wqf94p/